# PYTHON - Google Analytics - Upload Product Data - THROUGH API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Buy use Google Analytics API (V4) I would like to upload file "Product Data"

This is the sample code from GA Documentation

```
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
try:
  media = MediaFileUpload('custom_data.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
  daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
      customDataSourceId='9876654321',
      media_body=media).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

This is What I ahve done, but I still have an issue regarding this part - `analytics.management().uploads()`

```
import argparse

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# SET VARS
CUSTOM_DATA_SOURCE_ID='_xxxxxxx'
WEB_PROPERTY_ID='UA-xxxxx-1'
ACCOUNT_ID='xxxxxx'
CSV_IMPORT_FILE_LOCATION='test_file.csv'
CREDENTIALS_KEY_FILE_LOCATION='key.json'

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location):

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service

def uploadCSV(service):
  try:
    media = MediaFileUpload(CSV_IMPORT_FILE_LOCATION,
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
    daily_upload = service.management().uploads().uploadData(
        accountId=ACCOUNT_ID,
        webPropertyId=WEB_PROPERTY_ID,
        customDataSourceId=CUSTOM_DATA_SOURCE_ID,
        media_body=media).execute()

  except TypeError, error:
    # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v4', scope, CREDENTIALS_KEY_FILE_LOCATION)

  # Upload CSV Data
  uploadCSV(service)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This is an error which I have received all the time:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'management'
```

Any suggestions??

I assume that this is because I do not have these methods (management().uploads()) but this is what example from documentation says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current analytics api v4 only includes the reporting side of the API. To access the management endpoint you have to use v3. Try to rewrite your code using the v3 version of the API.

- [Here's what v3 looks like](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/analytics/analytics/v3/)
- [Here's what v4 looks like](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/analytics/analytics/v4/)

To start change this line:

```
service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, CREDENTIALS_KEY_FILE_LOCATION)
```

But it might require more rewriting than this.

Comment: My fault, I have spent time yesterday, to sort this out..... at the end this is was the solution, even so obvious...  But thank you)